# Asp.net share values across partial views

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am having trouble with sharing the values of my partial views across the views.

My main view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 5%;">
    <li id="first" role="presentation" class="active"><a>Anschrift</a></li>
    <li id="second" role="presentation"><a>Kunden Daten</a></li>
    <li id="third" role="presentation"><a>Preis / Zahlung</a></li>
</ul>

@model CustomerViewModel
<div id="inhalt">
    @Html.Partial("_General", Model)
</div>
```

The script for my view:

```
$("#first").click(function () {
    $("#inhalt").load('@Url.Action("General", "Home")');
});

$("#second").click(function () {
    $("#inhalt").load('@Url.Action("Data", "Home")');
});
```

`#first` and `#second` are buttons.

All views are nested inside a controller and my goal is to share the models across the partial views.

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Customer()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult General(CustomerViewModel model)
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_General.cshtml");
}

public ActionResult Data(CustomerViewModel model)
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_Data.cshtml");
}
```

Customer is the main view in which the partial views are getting rendered.

A snippet from my partial view:

```
@model CustomerViewModel
<h1>General Partial View</h1>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name1, new { @class = "text", placeholder = "Name 1", id = "Name1" })
```

**Edit**:

I tried the following code in order to share the model with the different views:

```
$("#inhalt").load('@Url.Action("Data", "Home", model)');
```

But this didn't seem to work because when I am debugging the controller everything in the model is null.

**Explanation:**

I press a list element which has an id (`#first, #second`..). The I want to replace the div with the id of `#inhalt` with my partial views. In order to do that I am using the javascript to replace the div with the partials, which all works fine. But I am not able to pass my model to the views. How do I achieve this?

Comment: So what is the specific problem or question? *"I am having trouble"* is a worthless problem description

Comment: I tried the following code: $("#inhalt").load('@Url.Action("Data", "Home", Model)'); in order to pass the model but this didn't work the model is still empty...

Comment: In your provided code, at no point do you set a `model` - so when you pass "it" back, of course it's null.  You need to load your model in your main page/view (`Customer()`?).   Bear in mind if you use `$().load("@Url.Action...` then the `model` will be passed on the url and you may have url length issues if you have a large model.   Question: Is there a reason you're not using `@Html.Partial`?   The `$.load` will load async which may be what you are after, but if the data is already loaded, then adds nothing as it's just async the render which is likely the smallest part.

Comment: That is just a code snippet inside of the view I am having the model and using it via textboxfor etc. I can't use @html.partial inside the load method or? What would be your apporach in order to get it working?

Comment: You can't use partial inside load, no - why do you think you need `$.load` ?  Why not replace all of `$(#..).load('@Url.Action("...` with `@Html.Partial("Data", "Home", model);`

Comment: Because I need to interact with the button when it is clicked. As well I need to replace my div with the content of the partial. Could you post your solution? I think I don't get what you mean

Comment: Ok - you might like to add more information to the question as to what it is you're trying to do.  As the question stands, there's no reason for it, hence you get questions rather than answers.  Trying to dynamically load the content based on a user action (button click) is certainly a reason to use `$.load`.

Comment: Next step - don't debug in VS, look at the rendered output in the browser: Navigate to the view then view-source in the browser, find that code and have a look.  That might also give you a potential reason.  I tend to pass simple data back in this scenario rather than a whole viewmodel, eg `public ActionResult General(int customerId)`

Comment: look at my edit I gave you an explanation. Yes it worked for me when I use $("#inhalt").load('@Url.Action("Data", "Home", new { Name1 = "test" })'); but when I use the model everything is null

Comment: Look at my edit... I added a snippet from my partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing in your model on the route (URI) you'll need to use Route Values here.

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DisplayData", "Home", Model.RouteValues)" alt="Image" />
```

As was shown in [Binding the Model variable to an Action Method in ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085914/binding-the-model-variable-to-an-action-method-in-asp-net-mvc3)

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public bool IsPeriod { get; set; }

    public RouteValueDictionary RouteValues
    {
        get
        {
            var rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();
            rvd["name"] = Name;
            rvd["surname"] = Surname;
            rvd["isPeriod"] = IsPeriod;
            return rvd;
        }
    }
}
```

or call directly using the Route Values

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DisplayData", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary(Model)" alt="Image" />
```

Keep in mind that because you are using the URL you can run across limits in length and the entire model may not fit, in that case you'd need to load via POST and not GET.