# How to pass a Javascript List object in @Html.Raw(@Url.Action())?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How do I pass a Javascript list object in @Html.Raw(@Url.Action()) ?

I have a Model in my controller which has the following properties as the js List object.

The Method in my controller expects this model.

```
   public ActionResult ExportDataExtReport( DataExtractionReportModel DataExtReportModel)
```

The call reaches the controller by the object is null

```
    ReportModel.push({
        ReportId : ReportSelID,
        ReportName : "DataExtraction",
        StartDate : DEYearSelID,
        CategoryId : DataExtCategoryId,
        SurveyId : QuestionnaireSelID,
        SurveyName: QuestionaireName,
        OperationalUnits : DataExtOpUnit
    });

   var link = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ExportDataExtReport", "Location", new { DataExtReportModel = -1}))';
    link = link.replace("-1", ,ReportModel[0]);
    window.location.href = link;
```

Comment: Your making a GET. You need to pass each individual name/value pair as a query string or route value

Comment: Normally I would use       JSON.stringify(ReportModel[0])   if it is an Ajax call and returns a View. But in this case I have to use  window.location.href as I need to generate an excel file. Is there any other way apart from passing each name/value pair as my model can have few more properties .

Comment: You can use the `$.param()` method to simplify it. But its not clear why your generating an object and then pushing it into an array - it would be less code just to generate the query string from the values. And you have not shown what all the property values are (`OperationalUnits` suggests a collection so that would not work anyway as you have shown it)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC is quite powerful understanding JSON data objects.

I don't know if it's the best practice, but I'll tell you how I manage them:

When I have a JSON data object on client code, before submitting to a new controller, I store it stringified in a hidden input.

Then I submit the form (which action is the controller method call). Now, my controller receives a form object, but one of their parameters is a stringified JSON object.

I usually have a business model class with a data structure compatible with those of the JSON data packages that reach the controller. Using JSON serializer and casting the result to that model class type makes your package date to load into an instance of your business model class.

Hope this helps

Comment: OP is making a GET, not a POST.

Comment: I didn't tried it with POST, but theoretically it should work aswell.

Comment: What? Again, the question is about making a GET using `location.href` - forms and hidden inputs are not applicable. This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I'm offering an alternate way to reach the ultimate goal (sending JSON object from client to controller), so you cannot say that it hasn't nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Your cannot do that with a `location.href`!

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment :

Is there any other way apart from passing each name/value pair as my model can have few more properties

yes there is a way , that is, you can just add **RouteValueDictionary** property to your existing model and send those values like below:

Related Example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public bool IsPeriod { get; set; }

    public RouteValueDictionary RouteValues
    {
        get
        {
            var rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();
            rvd["name"] = Name;
            rvd["surname"] = Surname;
            rvd["isPeriod"] = IsPeriod;
            return rvd;
        }
    }
}
```

**Then you can simply use the RouteValues property in your Url.Action() call.**

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DisplayData", "Home", Model.RouteValues)" alt="Image" />
```

**Or if your prefer less (explicit) code, ignore the model changes and simply do this:**

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DisplayData", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary(Model)" alt="Image" />
```

Source:https://stackoverflow.com/a/13088972/3397630

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: I seriously doubt that OP wants to send the original value of the model back to the server (would be a bit pointless)